# log4j 2 - collor logs for intelij console

Tags: log4j2, appender, pattern-layout

I try to config log4j to appends loggs in diffrent color per log type (INFO, ERROR, DEBUG etc.)
Here is my log4j2.xml:

```
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
        <Properties>
            <Property name="log-path">applogs</Property>
        </Properties>
        <Appenders>
            <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout>
                    <pattern>
                        %highlight{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36}.%M() [%L] - %msg%n}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green}
                    </pattern>
                </PatternLayout>
            </Console>
            <someMoreAppenders>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Logger name="RepositoriesController" level="info" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
            </Logger>
            <Root level="error" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender"/>
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

And in class RepositoriesController, i create logger in this way:

```
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("RepositoriesController");
   logger.info("Hello, World!");
```

My log4j.properties are empty. Output seems to be formatted used by my pattern but font color is still white:

[Intelij console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbQxR.png)

i tried to add this properties:
spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS
and modify pattern but without succesed, any advices?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] 
      %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue} - %msg%n" />
</Console>
```

`%highlight{%level}` - using this you can highlight colors for different levels of logs.

This will generate output as:

[image]